# Is there standard way of making multiple API calls combined into one HTTP request?

Tags: rest, http, batch-processing, standards, api-design

While designing rest API's I time to time have challenge to deal with batch operations (e.g. delete or update many entities at once) to reduce overhead of many tcp client connections. And in particular situation problem usually solves by adding custom api method for specific operation (e.g. `POST /files/batchDelete` which accepts `ids` at request body) which doesn't look pretty from point of view of rest api design principles but do the job.

But for me general solution for the problem still desirable. Recently I found [Google Cloud Storage JSON API batching documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch?hl=en) which for me looks like pretty general solution. I mean similar format may be used for any http api, not just google cloud storage. So my question is - **does anybody know kind of general standard (standard or it's draft, guideline, community effort or so) of making multiple API calls combined into one HTTP request?**

I'm aware of capabilities of http/2 which include usage of single tcp connection for http requests but my question is addressed to application level. Which in my opinion still make sense because despite of ability to use http/2 taking that on application level seems like the only way to guarantee that for any client including http/1 which is currently the most used version of http.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

- REST nor HTTP are ideal for batch operations.
- Usually caching, which is one of RESTs constraints, which is not optional but mandatory, prevents batch processing in some form.
- It might be beneficial to not expose the data to update or remove in batch as own resources but as data elements within a single resource, like a data table in a HTML page. Here updating or removing all or parts of the entries should be straight forward.
- If the system in general is write-intensive it is probably better to think of other solutions such as exposing the DB directly to those clients to spare a further level of indirection and complexity.
- Utilization of caching may prevent a lot of workload on the server and even spare unnecessary connecctions

---

To start with, REST nor HTTP are ideal for batch operations. As Jim Webber pointed out [the application domain of HTTP is the transfer of documents over the Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s). This is what HTTP does and this is what it is good at. However, any business rules we conclude are just a side effect of the document management and we have to come up with solutions to turn this document management side effects to something useful.

As REST is just a generalization of the concepts used in the browsable Web, it is no miracle that the same concepts that apply to Web development also apply to REST development in some form. Thereby a question like how something should be done in REST usually resolves around answering how something should be done on the Web.

As mentioned before, HTTP isn't ideal in terms of batch processing actions. Sure, a GET request may retrieve multiple results, though in reality you obtain one response containing links to further resources. The creation of resources has, according to the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3), to be indicated with a `Location` header that points to the newly created resource. `POST` is defined as an all purpose method that allows to perform tasks according to server-specific semantics. So you could basically use it to create multiple resources at once. However, the HTTP spec clearly lacks support for indicating the creation of multiple resources at once as the `Location` header may only appear once per response as well as define only one URI in it. So how can a server indicate the creation of multiple resources to the server?

A further indication that HTTP isn't ideal for batch processing is that a URI must reference a single resource. That resource may change over time, though the URI can't ever point to multiple resources at once. The URI itself is, more or less, used as key by caches which store a cacheable response representation for that URI. As a URI may only ever reference one single resource, a cache will also only ever store the representation of one resource for that URI. A cache will invalidate a stored representation for a URI if an unsafe operation is performed on that URI. In case of a `DELETE` operation, which is by nature unsafe, the representation for the URI the `DELETE` is performed on will be removed. If you now "redirect" the `DELETE` operation to remove multiple backing resources at once, how should a cache take notice of that? It only operates on the URI invoked. Hence even when you delete multiple resources in one go via `DELETE` a cache might still serve clients with outdated information as it simply didn't take notice of the removal yet and its freshness value would still indicate a fresh-enough state. Unless you disable caching by default, which somehow violates one of [REST's constraints](https://restfulapi.net/rest-architectural-constraints/#cacheable), or reduce the time period a representation is considered fresh enough to a very low value, clients will probably get served with outdated information. You could of course perform an unsafe operation on each of these URIs then to "clear" the cache, though in that case you could have invoked the `DELETE` operation on each resource you wanted to batch delete itself to start with.

It gets a bit easier though if the batch of data you want to remove is not explicitly captured via their own resources but as data of a single resource. Think of a data-table on a Web page where you have certain form-elements, such as a checkbox you can click on to mark an entry as delete candidate and then after invoking the submit button send the respective selected elements to the server which performs the removal of these items. Here only the state of one resource is updated and thus a simple `POST`, `PUT` or even `PATCH` operation can be performed on that resource URI. This also goes well with caching as outlined before as only one resource has to be altered, which through the usage of unsafe operations on that URI will automatically lead to an invalidation of any stored representation for the given URI.

The above mentioned usage of form-elements to mark certain elements for removal depends however on the media-type issued. In the case of HTML its [forms section](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) specifies the available components and their [affordances](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817). An affordance is the knowledge what you can and should do with certain objects. I.e. a button or link may want to be pushed, a text field may expect numeric or alphanumeric input which further may be length limited and so on. Other media types, such as [hal-forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [halform](http://halform.herokuapp.com/) or [ion](https://ionspec.org/#forms), attempt to provide form representations and components for a JSON based notation, however, support for such media-types is still quite limited.

As one of your concerns are the number of client connections to your service, I assume you have a write-intensive scenario as in read-intensive cases caching would probably take away a good chunk of load from your server. I.e. BBC once reported that they could reduce the load on their servers drastically just by introducing a one minute caching interval for recently requested resources. This mainly affected their start page and the linked articles as people clicked on the latest news more often than on old news. On receiving a couple of thousands, if not hundred thousands, request per minute they could, as mentioned before, reduce the number of requests actually reaching the server significantly and therefore take away a huge load on their servers.

Write intensive use-cases however can't take benefit of caching as much as read-intensive cases as the cache would get invalidated quite often and the actual request being forward to the server for processing. If the API is more or less used to perform CRUD operations, as so many "REST" APIs do in reality, it is questionable if it wouldn't be preferable to expose the database directly to the clients. Almost all modern database vendors ship with sophisticated user-right management options and allow to create views that can be exposed to certain users. The "REST API" on top of it basically just adds a further level of indirection and complexity in such a case. By exposing the DB directly, performing batch updates or deletions shouldn't be an issue at all as through the respective query languages support for such operations should already be build into the DB layer.

In regards to the number of connections clients create: HTTP from 1.0 on allows the reusage of connections via the [`Connection: keep-alive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header directive. In HTTP/1.1 persistent connections are used by default if not explicitly requested to close via the respective `Connection: close` header directive. HTTP/2 introduced full-duplex connections that allow many channels and therefore requests to reuse the same connections at the same time. This is more or less a fix for the connection limitation suggested in [RFC 2626](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4) which plenty of Web developers avoided by using CDN and similar stuff. Currently most implementations use a maximum limit of 100 channels and therefore simultaneous downloads via a single connections AFAIK.

Usually opening and closing a connection takes a bit of time and server resources and the more open connections a server has to deal with the more a system may suffer. Though open connections with hardly any traffic aren't a big issue for most servers. While the connection creation was usually considered to be the costly part, through the usage of persistent connections that factor moved now towards the number of requests issued, hence the request for sending out batch-requests, which HTTP is not really made for. Again, as mentioned throughout the post, through the smart utilization of caching plenty of requests may never reach the server at all, if possible. This is probably one of the best optimization strategies to reduce the number of simultaneous requests, as probably plenty of requests might never reach the server at all. Probably the best advice to give is in such a case to have a look at what kind of resources are requested frequently, which requests take up a lot of processing capacity and which ones can easily get responded with by utilizing caching options.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, interesting ideas and useful links but my question is about potential situation when it already decided (for some reason) to provide general batch operations for api (like developers of google cloud storage have decided) and the question is how to do that in some standard/conventional way? If I understand right there is no such way for a couple of reasons)

Comment: You seem to understand right. The batching mechanism design depends on your API design details - so if your API is genuinely new it is highly unlikely that anyone already created well-known specs for a suitable mechanism. Once you design how operations are batched, then HTTP can transport that batch information as a single request "API call".

Comment: @OlegKorobenko There will be no standard-compliant way in terms of HTTP IMO unless there is a new version of the protocol released that explicitely tackles that concern. This does not mean that you can't do it already. There are certain extensions to the HTTP protocol available, such as [WebDAV](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4918) that add new operations to the HTTP protocol. As such you might introduce new batch operations that specify how clients, servers and caches should handle such requests and standarize ist with [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

> reduce overhead of many tcp client connections

If this is the crux of the issue, the easiest way to solve this is to switch to HTTP/2

In a way, HTTP/2 does exactly what you want. You open 1 connection, and using that collection you can send many HTTP requests in parallel. Unlike batching in a single HTTP request, it's mostly transparent for clients and response and requests can be processed out of order.

Ultimately batching multiple operations in a single HTTP request is always a network hack.

HTTP/2 is widely available. If HTTP/1.1 is still the most used version (this might be true, but gap is closing), this has more to do with servers not yet being set up for it, not clients.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 also has multiple requests within a single TCP connection by default - they are just serial requests rather than parallel requests.

Comment: @AmosJeffries very true!