# Dealing with batch DELETE in REST API

Tags: rest, api, restful-url

I’m designing REST API and are about to deal with batch|single DELETE. Read a lot, understand that it is not advisable to allow batch delete. And will not try to feed multiple ids with parameters or do any POST hack.

What I came to is this:

```
DELETE /resources/{ID}:IamSure
```

Deletes resource with id {ID}

```
DELETE /resources/:IamSure[?filters][sort][limit]
```

Deletes resources matching optional filters within limit.

`:IamSure` is a „confirmation method” so it is impossible to invoke `DELETE` instead of `GET` by mistake. Other methods will throw error if `:IamSure` is added.

All above functions:

Backup full body of deleted resource/s plus response sent after operation success in JSON (possibly ziped) to cloud to:

```
/backup/resources/[{ID}/]apiuser_datetime
```

2 more functions:

`GET /backup/resources/[{ID}]` - returns list of backup URIs matching URL (/resource/[{ID}])

`GET /backup/resources/[{ID}/]apiuser_datetime` - returns backup body

Backup body can be directly used to recreate all deleted resources. If some connected resource will he missing, API will throw error.

Because I’ve build scope & method capability system for API users/apps on top of object capability system for system users (who ”own” API users/apps), any API user allowed by this 2 systems to `GET` particular resource/s will be also able to `GET /backup` of this resource/s - because method, scope and object capability match.

Any malicious or random attempt to delete resources would be recorded (who and when) and reversible - just POST body to the same URL.

Delete operations are not very common, so I don’t worry (now) about storage - especially because it will be cloud and seldom accessed.

Do you see any cons/problems in this aproach?

EDIT:

- Would you add other confirmation for batch DELETE like „:IamReallySure”? so „I forgot about id” would not result in havoc.
- Or would you leave DELETE /resource/{ID} without need for confirmation because it is standard behaviour in REST

Comment: I will move it there if it falls out of topic. There some discussions here about REST design so I’ve assumed it’s right place.

Comment: This question seems closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302537/is-there-standard-way-of-making-multiple-api-calls-combined-into-one-http-reques/60307179)

Comment: Interesting. Missed that. Thanks Roman.